# In ElasticSearch, how to combine a `span_near` and a `term`?

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query returns hits:

```
{
  "query": {
    "span_near": {
      "clauses": [
        {
          "span_term": {
            "file.contents": "charstreams"
          }
        }
      ],
      "slop": 0,
      "in_order": true
    }
  }
}
```

So does the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "file.extension": "java"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What's the query that combines the two such that both conditions are satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "span_near": {
          "clauses": [
            {
              "span_term": {
                "file.contents": "charstreams"
              }
            }
          ],
          "slop": 0,
          "in_order": true
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "file.extension": "java"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, since you're setting `slop` to `0` and `in_order` to `true`, you might want to consider using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html instead.